# Internet Explorer Run/Open download location

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I'd like to know where Internet Explorer stores a downloaded file if I click "Run" or "Open" instead of "Download".

Is it a directory like %temp%?

Answer (score 1):

#### Is it a directory like %temp%?

There is no environment variable containing the value of IE's Temporary Internet Files Folder.

---

#### Where is the Temporary Internet Files Folder located?

> Starting with Windows Vista, and continuing in Windows 7, the
>   Temporary Internet Files folder is located at:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
> ```
>
> In Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 the Internet Cache or Temporary Internet
>   Files are stored in this folder:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
> ```

Source [Temporary Internet Files Folder location in Windows 7 / 8](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/temporary-internet-files-folder-location)